# navigator.geolocation not working

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I'm working on a application that requires I get the users location info and I'm using the `navigator.geolocation` service to handle retriving the users latitude and longitude accordingly. Below is the code I have to retrieve their information.

```
let options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  console.log(position);
  console.log(navigator.geolocation);
}, function(error){console.log(error.message)});

console.log(navigator.geolocation);
```

However, I keeping running into this error below.

> Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403.

I checked to make sure the `navigator.geolocation` service was supported by my browser (I'm using Chrome) and it is and even went to log the object in the console which works and proves its not a browser issue. Does Google force certain machines out of their API repository? I'm so lost.

Comment: Your code does not produce the error reported

Comment: I ashould have stated that im using ionic 2 for this app,  which ic bound for typescript which would explain the let keyword for variables. However i tried using the builtin geolocation service for ionic 2 and i got the same problem,

Answer (score -1):

A quick check on console reveals that this API will work only on secure addresses, hence you're forbidden to use.

```
getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features for more details.
undefined
VM2552:4 Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)
```

Comment: Ahh I see.. I shouldve stated im using ionic 2 and am building towards a mobile app. I tried using the built in Geolocation service in ionic but i get the same problem.